# Paypal Express Checkout - Authorization not appearing in dashboard

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am creating & sending the following payment via the Express checkout API V4:

```
return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
    intent: 'authorize',
    payer: {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    transactions: [
        {
            amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'GBP' }
        }
    ]
});
```

and I'm returning the following object:

[image]

Which all seems to be on the right track. The problem is, there is no sign of this payment auth in the sandbox dashboard.

I've even tried using a live account, and sending a real penny, but there is no sign of the transaction in either the buyer or seller account.

If this payment is not being successfully created, why am I seeing the object returned with a state of `"created"`?

FYI: If I send a payment using `intent: 'sale'` it processes successfully and appears in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. API and documentation of PayPal is something awful...

The logic is this:

**1. You have to make execute payment.**

I tried to do it in different ways, but the easiest way ended up like this:

1. In the examples on the Paypal site show your complete code with  **onAuthorize: function(data, actions)** , so this function should look like this:

```js
 onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.payment.get().then(function(payment) {
    
    
                      console.log(payment);
    
                      var b = payment.payer;
                      var bb = b.payer_info;
    
                    //  alert (bb.payer_id);
    
                   var newUrl = "http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/execute.php?paymentId="+payment.id+"&token=EC-"+payment.cart+"&PayerID="+bb.payer_id;
    
                      console.log(newUrl);
    // go to the execute.php and send to paypal payment confirmation
                     window.location.replace(newUrl);
    
    
                  });
    
            }
```

**Once you got the object with a transaction you must still confirm it!**

2. Go here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation download the PHP SDK, it will need to file execute.php to easily confirm the payment and it showed up in the admin panel PayPal. I downloaded the SDK for a direct link, without Composer.
3. Then in the newly created file execute.php connect this directly SDK without Composer.

// Use below for direct download installation

```
require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
```

4. Then copy the contents of the file itself execute.php and replace it PayPal client ID and client secret. Full code of execute.php here http://pastebin.com/K750qcxE
   I couldn't paste here all the code. Citation of code here is terribly implemented, as well as PayPal API :)

p.s. in the script I sent to return url, but I don't know why paypal did not redirect me to it, so I redirect using javascript when you get the transaction object.

sorry for my english